# How does one fix a "The Resource Bundle Must Containt Title" error?

Tags: java, app-config, rad, websphere-7, websphere-portal

We are using WAS 7 server and also WebSphere portal server 6.1 on top of it. I imported my application into RAD, but there is an compilation error in the `portal.xml` file (located inside `web-inf`).

Error Message :

```
 IWAL0056E :THE RESOURCE BUNDLE MUST CONTAIN TITLE, SHORT-TITLE AND KEYWORDS.
```

in the following lines (`portal.xml`)

```
<supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
<supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
```

Could you please guide me to get out of this compilation errors...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that you didn't define the required entries in the resource bundle **.properties** file. Update it to reflect the following:

```
javax.portlet.title=yourTitle
javax.portlet.short-title=yourShortTitle
javax.portlet.keywords=yourKeywords
```

These values should directly map to the one defined inside `portlet-info` of portal.xml.

Comment: Could you please tell me location of the .properties file

Comment: Depends on your install path, but it will be there. Try to do a file search for *your-language-preference*.properties.

Answer (score 1):

You generally use the `<resource-bundle>` element with `<supported-locale>` (see *PLT.25.10 Resource Bundles* in the [JSR 286](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286)) - the bundles are loaded off your classpath if memory serves.

In your case, the files `WEB-INF/classes/foo/bar.properties` and `WEB-INF/classes/foo/bar_es.properties` should satisfy `<resource-bundle>foo.bar</resource-bundle>`.

These would have to contain the keys [Jops outlined in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20581984/304).